# Adding 2 numbers returns NaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add 2 numbers ("Co2" and "totalConsump") but somehow the result is NaN ("calculate"). I have tried to play with it, but nothing seems to be working. I checked, and the helper method getCo2Consump does work and returns a number.
Can anyone please help?

This is the method with a problem

```js
function calculateCO2() {
var totalConsump = 0;
var calculate = 0;
totalConsump = getCo2consump();
calculate = co2 + totalConsump;/*var of co2consumption in one chal*/;
setCo2(calculate);
  database
  .collection("Users")
  .doc(email)
  .collection("ChosenChallenge")
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
      database
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(email)
        .collection("ChosenChallenge")
        .doc(props.id)
        .update({
          Progress: percentRange,
        });
      database.collection("Users").doc(email).update({
        co2Saved: co2,
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And here is the helper function which calculates the number:

```js
function getCo2consump(){
  var co2Consump =[]; //this needs to be updated to be the co2consump from db later
  //get consump from databse
  var combinedConsump = 0;
  var i;
  database
  .collection("Users")
        .doc(email)
        .collection("ChosenChallenge")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            co2Consump.push(doc.data().Co2Consumption);
            
            
          });
          for (i=0; i< co2Consump.length; i++){
            combinedConsump = combinedConsump + co2Consump[i];
          }
          
          return combinedConsump;
})
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `co2` and `totalConsump`?

Comment: co2 is a useState, that is right now defined as 0. 
totalConsump is initiated as 0, but then it is supposed to be the value calculated from the helper method getCo2consump

Comment: Just before the calculation, add the following: `console.log(co2, typeof co2, totalConsump, typeof totalConsump)` so that you can verify the values and types of data that you are about to attempt to do math on.

Comment: Again, what are the *values* of these two variables before you sum them? I understand that both are *supposed* to be numbers. However, *evidently* that's not the case if you get `NaN`. We don't know which one is wrong or why, so the first step is to find what those values are so you can look into why the incorrect value is incorrect.

Comment: it seems like you didn't return combinedConsump in the function getCo2consump.

Comment: Also, if your goal with the loop is to add up add the individual sets of values, then the line should be: `combinedConsump += combinedConsump + co2Consump[i];`.

Comment: This is the result I get from that : NaN "number" undefined "undefined"

Comment: *This is the result I get from that : NaN "number" undefined "undefined"* <-- The result from what? Who are you replying to? We can't help you if you aren't very clear.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sorry about that, I'm new here. I was not aware that many comments would arrive.
This is the result I get from that : NaN "number" undefined "undefined" This was for you when you asked me to console log

Comment: @NhatAnh I'm not sure what you mean - there is a return - is it placed wrong?

Comment: My suggested code would produce more than just that since it asks for 4 values to be outputted. Please show ***exactly*** the output from that statement.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I copy pasted it in in your suggested spot, and this is the output I get NaN "number" 0 "number"
It is saying that co2 is NAN and typeof co2 is number, and totalConsump is 0 and type of totalConsump is number

Comment: Ok, so there you go. `co2` does not have the value you think it does. Now you should work backwards to determine why.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you for looking into it. Yes, I figured that it does not have the correct value then. It is a use effect, that is initialized like this: const [co2, setCo2] = useState(0); 
So I think what I don't understand, it why it is NaN, and not 0

Comment: An uninitialized variable doesn't just assume that it's a number, instead it becomes `undefined` and `undefined` is not a number.

Comment: @ScottMarcus okay that makes sense. How do I then initialize a useState, so that it works in this case?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I figured it out - thank you for it